# Change Span Text on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a shortcode in Wordpress that generates this button.

The code below is something generated by the shortcode, I'm trying to make the text change without changing any part this part of the snippet.

```
<div id="" class="addquotelistlink">
    <div class="quotelistadd">
        <span class="dvin_wcql_shopbtn_wrap">
            <button rel="nofollow" data-product_id="4246" data-product_sku="D410104" data-quantity="1" type="button" class="button alt addquotelistbutton product_type_simple">Request a Quote</button></span>

            <span class="dvin_wcql_shopbtn_ajaxico_wrap"><img style="display: none;border:0; width:16px; height:16px;" src="#" class="ajax-loading-img ajax-loading-img-bottom" alt="Working..."></span>
    </div>

    <div class="quotelistaddedbrowse" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#">In Quotelist</a>
    </div>
    <div class="quotelistexistsbrowse" style="display:none;;"><a href="#">In Quotelist</a></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="quotelistaddresponse"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to add some `onclick` effect when the button is pressed. So when the button is clicked I want it to change the color and text. I already figured out how to change the color, I just need help on changing the text. I'm been looking at different jquery ways but I'm not able to figure it out. So right now I have something like this.

So when the toggleClass 'active' is activated then it does the css class.

```
<script>
jQuery('.addquotelistbutton').click(function(){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});

</script>
```

//css

```
.addquotelistbutton.active {
    background-color: red;  
}
```

Can anyone help me change the span text now? I tried the following but it didn't work.

> $('.addquotelistbutton').html('Added to Wishlist');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **.text();** and check the class active to change the text to `Added to Wishlist` or return it back to `Request a Quote`

```
 jQuery('.addquotelistbutton').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
          jQuery(this).text('Added to Wishlist');
        }else{
          jQuery(this).text('Request a Quote');
        }
    });
```

> **Note:** your code `$('.addquotelistbutton').html('Added to Wishlist');` should work also but you just need to use $(this) 
>   inside click event

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you!

Comment: What was the problem and how does this solve it? `html()` should also have worked...

Comment: @VinceMamba glad it helped .. Good Luck :) .. and please don't forget to accept my answer ... Thanks

Comment: @showdev I updated my answer with a Note .. Thanks